# Get followers and following in one query using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ok lets say I'm making a social networks like twitter.
I have a table called social where it gets or where we put our social thing.

```
example me ( uid = 1 )
friend1 ( uid = 2 )
friend2 ( uid = 3 )
```

The table

```
SID AUID BUID
1   1    2
2   1    3
3   2    1
```

The information that we get here is

```
user id 1(me) is following 2
user id 1(me) is following 3
user id 2 is following 1(me)
```

And the question is: **Can we do something like the two queries below in one single query ?**

```
function CountFollowers($uid){
    $count = $this->fetch("SELECT COUNT(BUID) as followers
                                   FROM social WHERE BUID = :uid", 
    array( 'uid' => $uid));
    return $count;
}
```

and

```
function CountFollowing($uid){
    $count = $this->fetch("SELECT COUNT(AUID) as following
                                   FROM social WHERE AUID = :uid", 
    array( 'uid' => $uid));
    return $arrayofdata;
}
```

Thanks for looking in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This gets you two columns with the count of following and followers

```sql
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(BUID) as count FROM social WHERE BUID = :uid) as Followers
  , (SELECT COUNT(AUID) as count FROM social WHERE AUID = :uid) as Following
```

Comment: thanks!. yes im aware, because its the same as querying two database im i right?

Comment: @Mic - on what basis? If this query will be run often, I would have separate indexes on BUID and AUID, in which case this query will be the most efficient (separate lookups - count).

Answer (score 2):

Do you need `UNION` ?

```sql
SELECT 'followers' as `type`, COUNT(BUID) as count FROM social WHERE BUID = :uid
UNION
SELECT 'following' as `type` COUNT(AUID) as count FROM social WHERE AUID = :uid
```

Or you can do it in a different way :

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE 
WHEN BUID =:uid THEN 1
END) as  Followers,
COUNT(CASE
WHEN AUID=:uid THEN 1
END) as Following
 FROM social WHERE BUID = :uid OR AUID = :uid
```

Comment: @Adam Ramadhan: It doesn't matter; an argument can be anything not null, field or constant. `COUNT` returns the number of not-null values; `CASE` has default `ELSE NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(AUID, :uid)) AS MyFollowers,
  COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(BUID, :uid)) AS MeFollowing
FROM atable
WHERE :uid IN (AUID, BUID)
```

---

If `(AUID, BUID)` pairs are unique, then `DISTINCT` is not needed:

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(NULLIF(AUID, :uid)) AS MyFollowers,
  COUNT(NULLIF(BUID, :uid)) AS MeFollowing
FROM atable
WHERE :uid IN (AUID, BUID)
```

Comment: Andriy - why is there a `- 1`? Count does not "see" nulls

Comment: Nice, but brittle. e.g. `when :uid not in (distinct auid)`

Comment: @Richard: True, fixed that, I think. But it's not as nice now, thank you very much. Though probably `DISTINCT` is not needed now.

Comment: wow this one work, how does the nullif work ? what do we call this ?

Comment: @Adam Ramadhan: `NULLIF(a, b)` – returns `NULL` if `a = b`, otherwise returns `a`,

Comment: @Adam Ramadhan: And I'm afraid I haven't got an answer to your second question.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select Sum( Case When AUID = $uid Then 1 Else 0 End ) As Following
    , Sum( Case When BUID = $uid Then 1 Else 0 End ) As Followers
From Table
Where AUID = $uid
    Or BUID = $uid
```